# How to deploy Cordova app via CLI to a specified iPhone device?

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, command-line-interface

I am working with latest Cordova (4.3) on OS X and I have 2 iPhones attached to my Macbook Pro. Whenever I want to test my app, I run the following command in Terminal:

```
cordova run ios --device
```

The script produces the following output in Terminal:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
[....] Waiting up to 5 seconds for iOS device to be connected
[....] Found iPhone 4S 'iPhone 4S' (0b2799xxxxx) connected through USB.
[....] Found iPhone 4 (GSM) 'QA iPhone 4' (40daa94b6dc607595a570c0893ba54b185a85124) connected through USB.
[....] Waiting for iOS device to be connected
[....] Using iPhone 4S 'iPhone 4S' (0b27990xxxxxx) (0b2799xxxx).
------ Install phase ------
[  0%] Found iPhone 4S 'iPhone 4S' (0b279904xxxxxxx) connected through USB, beginning install
```

And then it proceeds to install the app on ONE of the iPhones, and opens up the lldb prompt. The 2nd iPhone remains dead and silent.

When I exit the lldb (via 'exit', 'y'), the scripts shows an error:

```
Quitting LLDB will kill one or more processes. Do you really want to proceed: [Y/n] y
Error code 253 for command: ios-deploy with args: -d,-b,/Users/path_to_app/appname.app
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Users/path_to_app/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

I looked all over Cordova CLI documentation and Google but I cannot see how I can deploy an app to a specific physical iPhone device (not emulator!). On Android, I can use "cordova run android --target=06af27413440e95f", where the long number is the device id in adb. How do I do that for iPhones?

I tried the following to no avail:

```
cordova run ios --target='QA iPhone 4'
cordova run ios --device='QA iPhone 4'
cordova run ios --device --target='QA iPhone 4'
```

Comment: did you try this `cordova run ios --target=0b27990xxxxxx`

Comment: yes, I did,  it responds with "0b27990xxxxxx is not a valid target for emulator" (the xxxx part is of course there to hide my real UDID)

Comment: Thanks @AtanuCSE your soultion worked for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hi I'm an ionic developer, however i clearly use cordova.
Let me try to help you.

Privet Sergey!

I use a shell script that uses ios-deploy node module that can deploy and debug through use of Xcode.

Firstly run this command to list all devices, you should see both of them ( FYI, is that normal to deploy to 2 devices at once using xcode? )

```
ios-deploy -c
```

For installation of ios-deploy , see (https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy)

Now for connecting and running commands to a specific device use this command:

```
ios-deploy  --id <device_id> --bundle my.app
```

There are shortcuts for this awesome command line tool.

```
    Usage: ios-deploy [OPTION]...
  -d, --debug                  launch the app in GDB after installation
  -i, --id <device_id>         the id of the device to connect to
  -c, --detect                 only detect if the device is connected
  -b, --bundle <bundle.app>    the path to the app bundle to be installed
  -a, --args <args>            command line arguments to pass to the app when launching it
  -t, --timeout <timeout>      number of seconds to wait for a device to be connected
  -u, --unbuffered             don't buffer stdout
  -n, --nostart                do not start the app when debugging
  -I, --noninteractive         start in non interactive mode (quit when app crashes or exits)
  -L, --justlaunch             just launch the app and exit lldb
  -v, --verbose                enable verbose output
  -m, --noinstall              directly start debugging without app install (-d not required)
  -p, --port <number>          port used for device, default: 12345
  -r, --uninstall              uninstall the app before install (do not use with -m; app cache and data are cleared)
  -1, --bundle_id <bundle id>  specify bundle id for list and upload
  -l, --list                   list files
  -o, --upload <file>          upload file
  -w, --download               download app tree
  -2, --to <target pathname>   use together with up/download file/tree. specify target
  -V, --version                print the executable version
  -e, --exists                 check if the app with given bundle_id is installed or not
```

Comment: Only noticed your answer now (because SO gave me a '1000 views' badge for this question) so... thanks, I guess :) Cannot confirm if it is working but it certainly seems like you know what you're talking about. Спасибо!

Comment: Adding an update: This tool may become deprecated in the future release of cordova-cli , they'll be able to deploy differently, through the cli tool itself without the new of this script.